# Ban "we are no longer accepting questions from this account." questions on MSO

Tags: feature-request, meta, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically redirect or block Meta questions regarding question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/automatically-redirect-or-block-meta-questions-regarding-question-bans)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130195/we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account

That's it. Could someone PLEASE filter questions on meta from low-reps that contain "we are no longer accepting questions from this account.", "http://goo.gl/C1Kwu", "help I cannot ask questions", and variants.

Make it so that if the question triggers the filter, they automatically get a popup: "read this first" with the monster duplicate post.

Or, make it closeable by 2 CVs. **Make Community ♦ auto-comment.** Or something. This is happening *way* too often.

(Also, I don't get how these guys can find meta and post here, but can't follow a stupid link and read it)

Note that the [official stance on these guys is "we don't care"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113179/178438), so I guess the devs won't want to waste time on this :/ . But *we* have to waste time on these questions, right?

---

Edit: I've seen the dupe. OK, forget blocking. Could we at least make CV-ing easier on these? Have Community ♦ auto-comment? Have a red popup come up? Make Community ♦ binding-CV after two votes?

Comment: There's the slight chance that someone posts a legitimate question containing that. So I think questions containing enough extra content shouldn't be auto-blocked. But yes.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yeah, that's there as well. Maybe have something that ensures that they have read the question (but then it gets complicated, and we shouldn't have the devs wasting time on qbanned users)

Comment: Perhaps if a ban is in place for a user on SO and he attempts to post on MSO, a popup saying `"If you were banned - read here..."`

Comment: And surely, since the block is in place on SO, when these phrases are posted in a question we can see if the request originated from the same IP/computer of the blocked SO account?

Comment: @Oded: Possibly.. Dunno how interconnected the sites are in the backend.

Comment: I don't think detecting the IP/machine would be needed.  If the accounts are linked and one of them has a ban in place - then the message is displayed...

Comment: @Lix - Most banned SO users will not have a linked account on MSO.

Comment: Flag exact dupes of [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/1288) and a moderator can delete them.  I do like to leave them for an hour or so to make sure the poster has a chance to see the link to the canonical Q&A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I am against globally banning anything especially here on Meta.
There is always the slight chance of legitimate requests when someone get banned by mistake; after all it's 100% automated system and mistakes happen.

Also, if we start banning such things, it will never end.

Let them rant, the moderators are doing great job of keeping the place clean and such posts get deleted in less than a day (after being closed in less than an hour, sometimes 10 minutes).

As for letting Community post a few closevotes or cast a binding vote after it reaches 2 CVs etc, such thing will be too complicated considering the gain in my opinion. We have more than enough members here to close such posts fast and enough moderators to delete them and keep the place clean.

Comment: Alright, what about something milder? Maybe have Community auto comment? `Have you read [this] yet?`?

Comment: that snarky community user... `tisk... tisk... tisk...` ;)

Comment: @Manishearth most I can think of that is legitimate is orange message box that can be dismissed.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: And what about letting Community post a few closevotes? Maybe have it cast a binding vote after it reaches 2 CVs?